# Running the R package reticulate in Docker environment

Tags: r, docker, dockerfile, reticulate

In a previous work, I used the 'reticulate' package to run the Autogluon autoML library in R.
The code works well in my current configuration (Ubuntu 20.4, R 4.10, reticulate v. 125).

However, this code doesn't work in Docker.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.0

## Install R packages
RUN R -q -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -q -e 'remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")'

# Install Autogluon
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::install_miniconda()'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-autogluon", packages = c("python=3.8.13", "numpy"))'
# RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_list()'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_install(envname = "r-autogluon", packages = "autogluon", pip = TRUE)'
RUN R -e 'reticulate::use_condaenv("r-autogluon", required = TRUE)'
# RUN -q -e 'reticulate::py_config()'

EXPOSE 3838
CMD R -e 'reticulate::import("autogluon.tabular")'

# Run in shell
# sudo docker build --no-cache -t demo .
# sudo docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 demo
```

I meet this error and I don't know how to solve it!

> reticulate::import("autogluon.tabular")
> Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) :
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'autogluon'
> Calls:  -> py_module_import
> Execution halted

## Tracks

- The 'conda_list()' indicates that the "r-autogluon" has been created with success!
- The 'py_config()' indicates that the "r-reticulate" is used by default.
- The 'reticulate::use_condaenv("r-autogluon", required = TRUE)' doesn't work.

Anybody has a solution ?

Comment: I vaguely remember that I have had problems with reticulate identifying the correct version of python even after using `use_condaenv`, and I had to specify with `use_python('/path/to/miniconda/envs/r-autogluon/bin/python')`, although that probably should have come up as a problem in `py_config()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RUN R -e` executes the command and closes the session :
`reticulate::import` doesn't find `autogluon.tabular` because `reticulate::use_condaenv('r-autogluon')` ran in another session, so that the `r-autogluon` environment isn't set in the current session.

In order to run specific initialization commands at session launch, you need to modify `Rprofile`, [see R startup](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), or `?Startup`.

You could `COPY` a modified version of `Rprofile`, or modify directly the file:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.1.0

## Install R packages
RUN R -q -e 'install.packages("remotes")'
RUN R -q -e 'remotes::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")'

# Install Autogluon
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::install_miniconda()'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-autogluon", packages = c("python=3.8.13", "numpy"))'
# RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_list()'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_install(envname = "r-autogluon", packages = "autogluon", pip = TRUE)'


## Modify Rprofile
RUN R -e 'write("reticulate::use_condaenv(\"r-autogluon\", required = TRUE)",file=file.path(R.home(),"etc","Rprofile.site"),append=TRUE)'
RUN R -e 'write("reticulate::import(\"autogluon.tabular\")",file=file.path(R.home(),"etc","Rprofile.site"),append=TRUE)'

EXPOSE 3838
```

Running the container in interactive mode now shows that `autogluon.tabular` is loaded (R is automatically launched because `r-ver` [docker file](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker-versioned2/blob/master/dockerfiles/r-ver_devel.Dockerfile) ends with `CMD ["R"]`):

```
docker run --rm -ti demo
```

```
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18) -- "Camp Pontanezen"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

Module(autogluon.tabular)
>
```

Comment: This is a very insightful answer.  Curious if there's a way to write the `RUN R -q -e` commands to execute multiple lines of R code at once with semicolons so they're executed in the same session.  Or to run an R script (as alternatives to editing Rprofile).

Comment: You can put two R commands together separated by `;`, for example `RUN R -e 'write("reticulate::use_condaenv(\"r-autogluon\", required = TRUE)",file=file.path(R.home(),"etc","Rprofile.site"),append=TRUE);write("reticulate::import(\"autogluon.tabular\")",file=file.path(R.home(),"etc","Rprofile.site"),append=TRUE)'` works

Comment: You can also `source()` any R script. I modified RProfile in order to be able to open an interactive session, but this isn't needed for a batch session.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't word my question well.  I'm asking if running multiple commands with semicolon or sourcing an R script could be ways to solve this problem without having to edit Rprofile.