# Use reticulate and python in docker container to deploy plumber api

Tags: r, dockerfile, reticulate, plumber

I am trying to deploy plumber API to Azure web service (as web app) using instructions from this site https://veerlevanleemput.medium.com/hosting-a-r-plumber-api-using-azure-app-service-4e78936787cf

I have problem with adding python and reticulate in the docker file and using it in plumber.R file.

Here is my Dockerfile (adjusted following this Stack overflow QA: [Running the R package reticulate in Docker environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73391888/running-the-r-package-reticulate-in-docker-environment)):

```
# Dockerfile
FROM rocker/r-base:4.2.1

# install the linux libraries needed for plumber
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
    && apt-get install -y \
        ca-certificates \
        build-essential \
        libprotobuf-dev \
        protobuf-compiler \
        cmake \
    libglib2.0-0 \
        libxext6 \
      libsm6  \
      libxrender1 \
      libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
        libxml2-dev \
        libsndfile1 \
        libx11-dev \
        libatlas-base-dev \
        libgtk-3-dev \
        libboost-python-dev \
        libsodium-dev \
        ffmpeg \
        python3-audioread \
        libssl-dev \
        openssl \
        python3-openssl \
        pkg-config

# RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y \
#    libssl-dev \
#    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
#    libsodium-dev

# create the application folder
RUN mkdir -p ~/application

# copy everything from the current directory into the container
COPY "/" "application/"
WORKDIR "application/"

# open port 8080 to traffic
EXPOSE 8080

# install packages
RUN R -e "install.packages('plumber')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('exuber')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('data.table')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('quarks')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('theft')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('tvgarch')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('mlr3')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('utils')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('https://github.com/MislavSag/finfeatures')"
RUN R -e "remotes::install_github('https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners')"

# Install Autogluon
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::install_miniconda()'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-tsfel")'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_install(envname = "r-tsfel", packages = "tsfel", pip = TRUE)'


# Install tsfel
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::install_miniconda()'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-tsfel", packages = c("python=3.8.13"))'
RUN R -q -e 'reticulate::conda_install(envname = "r-tsfel", packages = "tsfel", pip = TRUE)'

## Modify Rprofile
RUN R -e 'write("reticulate::use_condaenv(\"r-tsfel\", required = TRUE)",file=file.path(R.home(),"etc","Rprofile.site"),append=TRUE)'
RUN R -e 'write("reticulate::import(\"tsfel\")",file=file.path(R.home(),"etc","Rprofile.site"),append=TRUE)'

# install python and packages
# RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-venv python3-pip
# RUN python3 -m venv /home/rstudio/venv
# RUN /home/rstudio/venv/bin/pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
# RUN /home/rstudio/venv/bin/pip3 install tsfel

# when the container starts, start the main R script
ENTRYPOINT ["Rscript", "execute_plumber.R"]
```

Plumber.R file (I have only kept the function that is not working):

```
# plumber.R
# libraries
library(plumber)
library(exuber)
library(finfeatures)
library(runner)
library(reticulate)



#* mlr3 hft model v2 dsf
#* @param open open prices
#* @param high high prices
#* @param low low prices
#* @param close close prices
#* @param volume volume prices
#* @post /modeltsfel
function(open, high, low, close, volume) {
  
  # create OHLCV
  df = cbind.data.frame(symbol = "TEST",
                        date = seq.Date(from = Sys.Date() - 10, length.out = length(close), by = 1),
                        open, high, low, close, volume)
  ohlcv <- Ohlcv$new(df)
  
  RollingTheftInit = RollingTheft$new(windows = 240,
                                      workers = 1L,
                                      at = nrow(ohlcv$X),
                                      lag = 0L,
                                      na_pad = TRUE,
                                      simplify = FALSE,
                                      features_set = "tsfel")
  tsfel_features <- RollingTheftInit$rolling_function(ohlcv$X, 240, "close")
  
  return(tsfel_features[, 5])  
}
```

An finally here is my file that starts Docker:

```
# Execute plumber
plumber::plumb(file="plumber.R")$run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080)
```

All functions work, except above one, in which I want to use python module through docker.

Comment: what doesn't work?  do you have error messages?